# ios not enforcing encryption security parameters

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to encrypt some files in my ios app in order to prevent someone with a jailbroken phone to have access to the contents of my app's files.

I'm using the `Encrypting Your App's Files` from Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files

So I'm using this to write the file

```
let data = "hello".data(using: .unicode)!
try! data.write(to: fileURL, options: .completeFileProtection)
```

According to the docs, this option means:

> Complete. The file is accessible only when the device is unlocked.

So in the `AppDelegate` in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, I add this code that waits 5 seconds (to give time for the device to fully lock) and access the file:

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 5.0)
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .unicode)!)
```

I tried this on the actual device, locked the phone, waited 5 seconds, and the data read OK! I was expecting the reading to fail.

What am I missing?

PS: does this method actually guarantee that a jailbroken device the file will be unreadable in the filesystem?

Comment: You cannot project a file from someone who knows the passcode for the device, whether jail broken or not. File protection protects data at rest from attackers who don't have the passcode.  However, based on your test results it seems that the device was not locked at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is a setting to enable data protection under `project -> capabilities`. It was turned off therefore data was not being encrypted:

[image]